# How do I automate this in a shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I'm using the application [PlexConnect](https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnect) on my home server (a headless OSX box) and I have to ssh in (from an iMac) and manually kill the Python process sometimes with the following:

`ssh 192.168.0.7`

`ENTER PASSWORD`

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plex.plexconnect.bash.plist`

`ENTER PASSWORD AGAIN`

`sudo lsof -i ':80'`

`sudo kill -9 [PID OF PYTHON PROCESS]`

`sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plex.plexconnect.bash.plist`

I don't have a problem with this but my wife isn't particularly au fait with the command line. Is there any way I can create something on my iMac she can double click to do the whole thing?

Comment: Start with creating SSH keys and a sudoers rule with NOPASSWD. Then put your commands into a script and add the usual checks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure how to capture the PID from the `lsof` command though.

Answer (score 1):

So after setting up SSH keys and NOPASSWD entry in the sudoers file, you could do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ${UID} -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Must run script as root" >&2
    exit 1
fi

launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plex.plexconnect.bash.plist

#check what is running on port 80 and if the output matches 'python' then print the second column and pass it to kill
lsof -i ':80' | awk '/python/{print $2;}' | xargs kill

launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plex.plexconnect.bash.plist
```

I haven't tested that, but it should give you an idea of how proceed.

And you could have something on your other computer:

```
#!/bin/bash
server_ip=1.2.3.4
ssh_cmd="ssh -oBatchMode=yes ${server_ip}"
${ssh_cmd} 'sudo /path/to/above/script.sh'
```